# Should I throw an exception, return an error code, or print out some log and call abort()?

Tags: exception, return-code

I have a class as follows:

```
class MyBuffer
{
    private:
        char* ptr_;
    public:
        MyBuffer(char* ptr_tmp) : ptr_(ptr_tmp) {};
        void write_data(int val)
        {
            if(ptr_ == NULL)
            {
                // What should I do here?
                // throw an exception, return error code, or just abort()?
            }

            // Write val to the buffer pointed by ptr_
            // ...
        }
};
```

ptr_ cannot be changed after initialization. That means that the statement `ptr_ == NULL` will be `true` if and only if developers pass a NULL pointer in the constructor. If this occurs, either throwing an exception or returning an error code, the handling code should TERMINATE program right away.

I have read several discussions about exceptions and errors. It seems to me that exception should be used for 'predictive' but 'exceptional' cases. In my example, if `ptr_ == NULL` is true this would be not an exception but a bug, right?

Comment: Arguably, you should bail out during initialization if passed a NULL pointer, not at an unknown later time.

Comment: @mustaccio If I had checked `NULL pointer` in the constructor would I have to check it later on (e.g. in write_data)?

Answer (score 0):

An age-old dilemma.

Doesn't it really come down to your class design, what the contract is with the consumers?

If write_data() should never not-write, then an exception is in order, except I'd consider throwing it from the constructor.  I always like to fail fast, so as soon as you know the pointer is invalid because write_data will never work, then throw it there.  Some people disagree with throwing exceptions from a constructor because it can leave a partially instantiated class, but that seems minor.  In the actual {} check for null and throw whatever is appropriate (in Java, you'd likely throw an InvalidArgumentException).

You could essentially do a lazy initialization if there's no guarantee that write_data() will actually be called, and therefore throw it the first time the method is called.

If the contract does not guarantee that anything is written to the buffer, and a null pointer therefore is valid, then just log a message and move on.

[I'd actually log something regardless, makes debugging easier, though the log level might be SEVERE/FATAL vs. WARNING/INFO.]